# Does Rstudio server keeps running my code if I sign out?

Tags: r, function, rstudio, wrds

I am currently using Rstudio server for running a very long function in order to make it run faster. I wanted to know what happens to the debug if I log out or close my laptop. Does the code on the server keep running or does it stops until I sign in again?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running the RStudio server on your laptop, the session should continue running even if log out or close your laptop.

Comment: Might depend on the type of server/how they're connected tho. For example, the rstudio server of my lab is mainly used through our browser (like 'my.lab.address.com/rstudio). So in that case, disconnecting means closing the tab, which closes Rstudio and stop the analysis.

But yeah, otherwise unless deconnection specifically stop this user's processes, it should keep running. Should be pretty easy to test tho.